# HTML5 Video does not work in IE9

Tags: html

I’m having a problem getting HTML5 to work in IE9. It showed up as a failure to execute the video tag. It works fine in Firefox, Opera and Safari but I just got a blank screen in IE. This is the code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="video1.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>
```

Then I ran the HTML5 compatibility test at http://html5test.com and I also got a blank screen in IE, so it’s more than the video tag that’s at issue.

Then I tried running an `.mp4` sample video online ( http://archive.org/details/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4 ) - it does not run within the browser, but opens in VLC player! In Firefox, Opera and Safari, it runs in the browser.

I’ve reinstalled IE – no good. When I check the IE version, it says Internet Explorer 9, but after "Version:", there's a blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` have you used?

Comment: Check the encoding of the .mp4. Turn off VLC player. If the video cannot play natively in Internet Explorer it is most likely an encoding issue.

Comment: this link may help you   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that my server wasn't returning the correct MIME type for the video object. Check out this guy's info - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/07/20/html5-video-not-working-in-ie9-some-tips-to-debug.aspx

I just added this code to my .htaccess file and it worked immediately - 
 `AddType video/mp4 .mp4`

Answer (score 0):

use [**[HTML5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)**] to enable HTML5 tag for Internet Explorer. And add WebM video format to the sources

Comment: Ups I don't know that. Yeah I just tried using tag <code>video</code> and test it to IE9 but it's not working. weird. I also have checked [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video) and it said video tag should be working in IE9